# Ext.getElementById does not work from Ext.Controller init or onLaunch events

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc, extjs4.1

I have the following `Ext.getElementById` call from a specific part of application code, that does work when called in this context:

```
init: function() {
    // template method called when app boots; before Viewport is created

    this.control({
        'launcherlist': {
            itemclick: function (dataView, record) {
            Ext.getElementById('element-id');
         },
    }
    ...
}
```

However I need to call the `getElementById` at an earlier stage, *before having any user- triggered event occurring*.

When `getElementById` is called directly within [`init`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-method-init) it doesn't work as `init` is called when app boots; before Viewport is created.

So I decided to override the controller's [`onLaunch`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-method-onLaunch) event, since `onLaunch` is a template method like `init`, but is called after Viewport is created:

```
onLaunch: function() {
    Ext.getElementById('element-id');
},
```

However this didn't work either.

**TL/DR**

Where can I put a *working* `Ext.getElementById` call before any user-triggered-action takes place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Since the widget that renders the DOM element I'm looking for extends `Ext.view.View`, the correct event *after which* `Ext.get` can actually find the rendered element is the `viewready` event.

P.S. One should use `Ext.get` anywhere rather than `Ext.getElementById` as the latter is a *private* method.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to explain what you're trying to do. getElementById is a "private" method, you shouldn't really be calling it. If you want to get an element by id, use Ext.get.

Comment: I have to simply retrieve an element by id, in my case it's a `td` with id `about-launcher`. Previously the widget's constructor in which this code resides was called following a user-initiated action (from the `controller`). Now I need to initiate the widget before any user-initiated action. But `Ext.get` (I +1ed your suggestion which indeed is a better approach) does not work (returns `null`) when called from the controller's `onLaunch` event.

Comment: If I run `Ext.get('about-launcher');` in the Chrome console after load, the statement works.

Comment: onLaunch is likely too early, you should listen to the render event of the component.

Comment: Thanks Evan. Isn't there a controller event similar to `onLaunch` that is called after *all* child components of the viewport are rendered?

Comment: Evan is right; the `render` event is where you should put it. I've just checked with my code and it works (running Ext.getElementById from the render event). So either you hook on the wrong render event or the element you are looking for is not rendered when the view loads (could happen for submenu items etc.)

Comment: @Izhaki I think I forgot to disclose an important piece of info. My "widget" extends `Ext.view.View`. The event that I should have been listening to is `viewready`. Now it works! Apologies for the missing piece of info!

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Can you edit your answer to instruct me to use `viewready` since my widget extends `Ext.view.View`? Then I'll mark it as correct. Thanks.